# Pod error when use Twitter and Google pods in my podspect Swift, objective c libraries

Tags: objective-c, swift, dependencies, cocoapods, specifications

I created a pod that need to TwitterKit and GoogleSignIn because is a pod of user authentication, but when i create a project and try to install the pod, in

```
pod install
```

return this error, in internet its a common error but nobody fix it, and apparently its because twitter and google are a Objective C libraries

anybody know how i can reference thats pods in my pod and podspect without any conflicts????

```
[!] The 'Pods-Project' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: 
(/Users/username/Documents/Project/Pods/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework
and /Users/username/Documents/Project/Pods/TwitterKit/TwitterKit.framework)
```

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3267

Comment: it doesn't work, im already try it

Comment: you can't have the same pod linked as framework and static library at the same time, try to remove every library/framework and add one by one again

Comment: @Lu_ actually its posible, try with swift libraries as FacebookSDK, also, i don't refer the twitter or google pods in both projects, only in my pod spec, thats not is the problem